# Validate several controls with CustomValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I am building a feature for users to change their passwords. So this means I have three text fields that need to be validated (is current == actual current, and is new == repeat). So I'm trying to build a custom validator for the first time, and am not sure how to do this. From another example I've seen, the validator is tied to one input field only, which means the ControlToValidate property is rather self-explainatory. But now, though?

I'm trying to do this:

```
var passwordValidator = new CustomValidator()
            {                   
                Display = ValidatorDisplay.None,
                ValidationGroup = "PasswordValidationGroup"
            };

passwordValidator.ServerValidate += ChangePasswordServerValidate;

ValidationPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(passwordValidator);
```

But I'm not getting the results I'm after. The validator does get executed when expected, and debugging shows it follows the if/else-structure as expected, but the error message never does get set. So how do I set it to validate three controls? Is it related to ValidationGroup somehow? I just set that property similarly to how it was in that other custom validator.

```
private void ChangePasswordServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            var validator = sender as IValidator;
            var user = SessionManager.Get<OrderFacade>(SessionKeys.OrderFacade).User;

            if (CurrentPasswordTextBox.Text == "" || NewPasswordTextBox.Text == "" || RepeatPasswordTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                validator.ErrorMessage = SiteTextResources.CreateAccount_YourEmailAddressEmpty;
                e.IsValid = false;
            }
            else if (!NewPasswordTextBox.Text.Equals(RepeatPasswordTextBox.Text))
            {
                validator.ErrorMessage = SiteTextResources.CreateAccount_YourEmailAddressEmpty;
                e.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ResolveClient<IUserClient>().TryPassword(user.UserName, CurrentPasswordTextBox.Text, passwordSuccessfullyChanged =>
                {
                    e.IsValid = passwordSuccessfullyChanged;
                    validator.ErrorMessage = String.Empty;
                }, error =>
                {

                });
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message doesn't get set because you are setting the display to `None`. Change it to `Static` or `Dynamic`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

- **None** -   The validation message is never displayed inline.
- **Static** - Space for the validation message is allocated in the page
  layout.
- **Dynamic** -    Space for the validation message is dynamically added to the
  page if validation fails.

As for the validation details, if you need to check the contents of 3 controls, do it inside the `ChangePasswordServerValidate` method and set the `e.IsValid` accordingly. The `ControlToValidate` property is not relevant here.

Comment: I did remove the ControlToValidate a little while ago, after stumbling across some forum post. But the error message still isn't displaying. Changing Display to Static or Dynamic didn't help either :( (fwiw, all other validators have "None" set).

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson add the code for the ChangePasswordServerValidate method please